# My CSS File not loading in Django but Bootstrap file loads fine

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple website running on Django.  When I load Bootstrap css files, the page loads the formatting just fine. But I try to load the css file I have created and saved in the same folder as the Bootstrap css files, the file does not load. See the file here http://jsfiddle.net/zptkvx5c/ In both case I am making reference to the file in the html head.

```
<link href="{% static "css/mystyles.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"> 
<!--  <link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">  --> This one works
```

Could anyone assist to fix this?

Update: 
I have tried to hardcode the url and still it doesn't work

Comment: are you sure that `mystyles.css` file is present in `css` directory?
Did you do `python manage.py collectstatic` after adding this file?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed the mystyles.css is in the folder. I have not run collectstatic. I am using the django development server with debug=true it seems to load Bootstrap ok. Any personal css files will only be served with the collectstatic command?

Comment: What does it say in the js console? Also, try swapping the order, `bootstrap.css` first and then `mystyles.css`

Comment: Thank you @ ham-sandwich I have never used the js console before. I have realised I have been trying to solve the problem and made a mistake.

Comment: I had made an app level static folder (toplevel/appfolder/static/appfolder) and put a bootstrap folder there. This is the one that was being loaded. However I was trying to set up a project level static folder where I had put another Bootstrap folder and the styles.css file I was trying to load. (projectfolder/staticfolder) Perhaps can you advise me how to reference the project level static folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this one:

```
<link href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

or

```
   {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mystyles.css" %}" type="text/css">
```

This one works

[SEE THE PAGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/)

Comment: This does not work, shouldn't there be a reference to the static folder?

Comment: Now see My answer sir@Avagut

Comment: Thank you @ivin raj does this reference an app level static folder or a project level static folder ie. where I can put static files to be used in all apps?